# devDemon Forms - Stripe gets no receipt_email for guest payments

Tags: stripe, devdemon-forms

We have DevDemon forms up and running, our form works, payments go through our Stripe account in test mode.

- We are processing payments for guests of the EE installation, not registered EE users.
- We have an Email field which has a short name of receipt_email.
- Stripe says there is no email passed, so no receipt can be emailed out.

**Question:**
Is it possible to pass the email from the form (receipt_email) as the email for stripe to use when sending out a receipt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your email field set as Master?

[image]

Comment: We sure do. But it still didn't work. Manuel sent a patch that he said should fix this issue. I'll try it out and see how it goes and report back here.

Comment: The patch given works great. Hope to see this in the new live version soon, if not already.